# What all can be an endpoints in Websphere ESB

Tags: websphere, esb

Can anyone tell me what all can be the endpoints on an Websphere ESB. Like a web service, bpel process etc. what else can be there.!?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Before I attempt to answer your question, I would like to bring something important to your attention

**WebSphere ESB product has been sun-set.** The product features have been merged into IIB (earlier called as WebSphere Message Broker).

If you are starting now, I would suggest that you explore IIB instead of WESB.

WESB can expose services via multiple means - WebServices (SOAP/HTTP and JMS) and messages (via both JMS or MQ).

In WESB terms we call them as exports. Exports are the ways by which a service is exposed to the external world.

Note: BPEL processes cannot be hosted in a WESB environment.